# variable in ionic 3 when making http request

Tags: ionic-framework

I am a newbie. So I don't understand how variables run in ionic 3. I can't read the value of variables in constructor function when I make a HTTP request. Can anyone help me? thank you, pro.

```
constructor(private fire: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http) {

    this.email = fire.auth.currentUser.email;
    this.films = this.http.get('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/329601/feeds.json?results=10');
    this.films
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
            this.dulieu = data.feeds;
            console.log("Du lieu", this.dulieu[2].field2);
        })
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoggedinPage');
}
```

Comment: How can I get data out of constructor

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Ionic3. You should first learn angular4. Go through this [Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) and you'll know everything you need to know.

Comment: @duongle if it helps +1 me :) or if this answer worked for you make it as the answer :) thank you

Comment: Yep, I just voted. Can you show me how save data (json) in variables after making a http request? I tried to find some examples but it's not useful. Thank you

Comment: @duongle you don't have anything special to do. Just assign to a variable. In above code this.duelie have to define first (as duelie:any;) above constructor.

Comment: I know, but my json data follow:{
    "channel": {
        "id": 329601,
       
        
      
        "field1": "Độ ẩm đất",
        "field2": "Đổ ẩm không khí",
        "field3": "Nhiệt độ",
        "created_at": "2017-09-12T02:43:00Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-11-15T08:44:20Z",
        "last_entry_id": 1749
    },
    "feeds": [
        {
            "created_at": "2017-11-08T11:03:24Z",
            "entry_id": 1740,
            "field1": "0.00",
            "field2": "65.40",
            "field3": "27.90"
        }, how can I save it?

Comment: I defined as: dulieu: any[] and used: this.dulieu=data in http request. But the result is: undefined

Comment: console.log(data); Does this gives you any output? is it logged on your console? if it is undefined you don't receive anything from request? you are still using above code i guess?

Comment: I recive data but I can save it in a variable(here is dulieu, dulieu is a variable which I want it to save data json from http request)

Comment: Cannot understand with what you have provided. Can you reproduce this issue using https://stackblitz.com/ and share the link

Comment: As you know, when we make a http request, data is asynchronous. This means that your code will continue executing whilst the data is being fetched, which could take anywhere from a few milliseconds, to 10 seconds, to never. So the problem here is: How can I store data in a variable

Comment: still it doesn't matter the time. If you can console.log(data) it is fetched already.  So for now at least try to reproduce and share it thank you.